# Django 1.2 won't run my view

Tags: django

I'm getting a 404 from my Django server even though it's aware of my view code. If I purposely misspelled the name of the view function, Django complains, so I know it's looking in the right place and that it is aware of this function.

My `urls.py` entry looks like this

```
url(r"^pdfgen/$", 'apps.pdfgen.views.pdfgen'),
```

And my view code is this

```
def pdfgen(request):
    html = "<html><body>This is a test.</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

So why is it that `Django 404's` when I visit `localhost:xxxx/pdfgen/` ?

Comment: Its not`localhost.com` but simply `localhost:8000/pdfgen/` (you need the trailing slash)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: while you are likely right about localhost vs localhost .com, there is certainly nothing preventing someone from adding a host record pointing localhost.com to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: True but I doubt that the case here, besides `localhost.com` is already a registered domain.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: It doesn't matter if it is a registered domain.

Comment: I wasn't thinking there. That's not actually what I'm writing in my address bar. I just said that as an example to show you that that wasn't the problem... ironically.

Comment: In your settings do you have append_slash?

Comment: @Mustack: Are you including the trailing slash as BurhanKhalid pointed out?

Comment: One you add the trailing slash, you should get a 500 error page since `now` is never defined in your view code.

Comment: Those are good considerations but it didn't resolve my issue. I actually caught the undefined variable thing before posting but forgot to recopy the code. I've edited my post. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> If I purposely misspelled the name of the view function, Django complains, so I know it's looking in the right place and that it is aware of this function.

That doesn't mean that your request is hitting the correct view - it just means that Django can't load your url conf when you include views that don't exist. To be sure that Django is running the view you think it is, you need to add some logging or print statements to the view, or raise an exception in it.

Update your question to include all your url patterns. Your request is probably matching a view further up, which is returning the 404.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is an existing codebase that I'm working with and the urls.py file is huge. On top of the that, there are many sub-directories with with many more urls.py files. Is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much! I decided to move my entry to the top and now it works. It seems there was a wildcard url to catch anything that wasn't specified before it and my url was coming after.